# How to Backup app data similar to whatsapp

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, drive, android-backup-service

Hi I am trying to implement backup funcationality similar to whatsapp, but when I come across that after reverse engineering whatsapp manifest code. Here are the observations,
android:allowBackup="false" which means Its not taking help of default AutoBackup functionality or any backupagent

[image]
But under some obeservations, how this backup is working , check below screenshort
[image]

And I need to have unlimited storage limit, unlike AutoBackup with <25mb,

ex: currently my whatsapp backup is holding 112mb size

Comment: You should use Drive SDK: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro
WhatsApp backups are not the ones specified in the manifest, but they are done by a lot of code.
Moreover, I think that WhatsApp backups show there because of a Google special permission, other apps backups are listed only by clicking the gear in the top-right corner

Comment: I was asked this question in a interview